# Read some particular elements of a HDF5 dataset in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, data-structures, dataset, hdfs, hdf5

I have an HDF5 dataset, generated by MATLAB, which one of its datasets is of size [1 12672 1 220000] following the pattern: [height width channel NumberOfInstances]. In other words, I have 220000 vector samples reshaped into an 4-D data structure. Now, I want to read the first elements of all vector samples in MATLAB and do some operations, say average, on them.
Here is the thing that I tried (not sure if it is correct), but I got into a pool of errors:

```
data = h5read('trial.h5','/data',[1 1 1 1],[220000,1,1,220000]);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you google "hdf5 read matlab"? gives: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hdf5read.html

Comment: Yeah, I have already worked with high-level hdf5 commands, but I don't know how to do the indexing to to read the first elements of the all vectors.

Comment: Show what you tried then!

Comment: Here is what I tried but I get into lots of errors: 
data = h5read('trial.h5','/data',[1 1 1 1],[220000,1,1,220000]);

Comment: And that does not work? It should in theory...

Comment: "The index arguments exceed the size of the dataset."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dataset is size  `[1 12672 1 220000]`.

you are accessing it using `data = h5read('trial.h5','/data',[1 1 1 1],[220000,1,1,220000]);`

The amount of data you want to access is `[220000,1,1,220000]`.

You dont have that amount of data!!! the first dimension is just `1`. You can no access the first `220000` values of the first dimension because they dont exist, there is only `1`.